# Регулярные выражения с условием

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Имеется ссылки двух видов:

1. https://www.test.com/common/inc/productDetail_price.jsp?skuId=2260697&productId=xlsImpprod4130103
2. https://www.test.com/milk?productId=xlsImpprod18451151

Суть задачи такова: если в ссылке **не** содержится 'productDetail_price.jsp', то вывести значение параметра 'productId'

Как я делаю:

```
(?<!productDetail\_price\.jsp.).*productId=(\w+) - работает неверно, выводит оба варианта.
```

Если использовать противоположный вариант:

```
(?<=productDetail\_price\.jsp.).*productId=(\w+) - выводит противоположный вариант, который мне нужен
```

**Важный момент:** задачу необходимо решить только регулярными выражениями

Адрес для тестов: http://rubular.com/r/6YZVmhMbUj

Буду рад любым советам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую распарсить URL с помощью стандартного [`URI`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/URI.html) + [`CGI`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html):

```
s = 'https://www.test.com/common/inc/productDetail_price.jsp?skuId=2260697&productId=xlsImpprod4130103'
uri = URI.parse(s)
if uri.path.split('/').last != 'productDetail_price.jsp'
    puts CGI::parse(uri.query)["productId"]
end
```

**Подробности**

- `uri = URI.parse(s)` - инициализируем объект URI
- `if uri.path.split('/').last != 'productDetail_price.jsp'` - разбиваем полученный "путь" по `/` и проверяем последний элемент списка. Если он не равен `productDetail_price.jsp`,
- `CGI::parse(uri.query)["productId"]`  - парсим строку запроса и берем значение параметра `productId`.

[**Онлайн-демо на Ruby**](https://ideone.com/hRsYju)

Если `productDetail_price.jsp` может находиться в любом месте URL, можно заменить `if uri.path.split('/').last != 'productDetail_price.jsp'` на

```
if !uri.path.include? 'productDetail_price.jsp'
```

**Регулярное выражение**

Если нужно решение на основе регулярного выражения, используйте

```
s[/^(?!.*\bproductDetail_price\.jsp\b).*productId=(\w+)/, 1]
```

или

```
s[/^(?!.*\bproductDetail_price\.jsp\b).*productId=\K\w+/]
```

См. [демо выражения на Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/XmoEDaYHNV)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*\bproductDetail_price\.jsp\b)` - в строке не должно быть целого слова `productDetail_price.jsp` (точка экранирована, чтобы находила только символ `.`, `\b` — это границы слова, `(?!...)` — негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, если его шаблон находит совпадение, совпадение всего шаблона не находится).
- `.*productId=` - 0 и более любых символов (кроме знака перехода на новую строку), как можно больше, до последнего вхождения последующих шаблонов, и потом `productId=`
- `(\w+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 1+ букв, цифр или `_`
- `\K\w+` - альтернатива - можно использовать `\K`, чтобы очистить буфер совпадения, и, таким образом, в нем окажутся только последние 1+ букв, цифр или `_`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению такой вариант не подойдёт, т.к. задачу необходимо решить именно регулярным выражением

Comment: @Зефиркавшоколаде Это еще почему? Ruby - полноценный язык программирования, зачем вам "регулярочный костыль"?

Comment: Такие уж условия задачи

Comment: @Зефиркавшоколаде Не завидую я вам, если честно, если вы, конечно, не отвечаете, как я, в течение 4 лет каждый день на SO на вопросы относительно регулярных выражений. В таких случаях, регулярки становятся неуправляемо сложными.

Answer (score 0):

С использованием предпросмотра назад надо исправить так:

```js
function check(s) {
  var m = s.match(/(?<!productDetail_price\.jsp.*)\bproductId=(\w+)/)
  return m && m[1]
}

console.log(check("https://www.test.com/common/inc/productDetail_price.jsp?skuId=2260697&productId=xlsImpprod4130103"))
console.log(check("https://www.test.com/milk?productId=xlsImpprod18451151"))
```

Но его можно и вообще не использовать:

```js
function check(s) {
  var m = s.match(/^(?!.*productDetail_price\.jsp).*\bproductId=(\w+)/)
  return m && m[1]
}

console.log(check("https://www.test.com/common/inc/productDetail_price.jsp?skuId=2260697&productId=xlsImpprod4130103"))
console.log(check("https://www.test.com/milk?productId=xlsImpprod18451151"))
```

Comment: А причем тут JavaScript? К тому же, первое решение сработает только в среде, поддерживающей ECMAScript 2018 (стоило бы отдельно указать).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спрашивали регулярку, в ответе - две версии регулярки. Демонстрация, что они работают в js - чисто для проверки верности регулярок. На руби я писать не умею.